# what will be happend when inserting integer value as string in sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server

the table structure is

```
empid int identity
empname varchar(50)
empage int
```

while i am inserting values to the table by following query

```
insert into tablename values('g','4');
```

now the query is executing well.

So whats the difference between the  following query and above query

```
insert into tablename values('go',5);
```

Comment: Depends on the RDBMS.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen: Couldn't get u

Comment: The RDBMS..... looks like SQL Server with Identity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first query will do an 'implicit cast' from literal `varchar` value '4' to the value 4 (an `INTEGER`)

The second one will not.

The second one is a bit better practice.

Both of them are bad practice regardless because you should include the column names as well:

```
insert into tablename (empname,empage) 
values('go',5);
```

Comment: other than this cast, is there any other difference? like memory usage or processing time to convert..?